# How do I put the output in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, list

How do I put the output generated in an array? I then want to subtract each element by its preceding element. For example: 6-0, 7-6, 10-7 etc to get the running length.

```
for index, item in enumerate(binary_sequence):
    if item == 1:
        print(index)
```

Output:

```
6
7
10
11
15
16
19
30
35
44
48
49
51
54
55
56
57
60
74
76
78
80
85
90
97
98
```

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: "Arrays" are called *lists* in Python. That is probably why you were unable to find [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: Input is a list of 0's and 1's, and in the code above I found the indices at which 1 is found. Now I need to find the run lengths. For example for 001000100011: Run length is 3441

Comment: You should [edit] your question and put that information **in** it.

Answer (score 0):

Python has ways to avoid indexing for common manipulations

`zip` lets you pair lists and iterate over the paired values, pairing a list with a offset version of itself is common

```
seq = [*range(7, 30, 4)]

seq
Out[28]: [7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27]

out = []
for a, b in zip(seq, [0] + seq):  # '[0] + seq' puts a '0' in front, shifts rest over
    out.append(a - b)

print(out)
[7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: But how do I put this output which is not in a list, into an list first before doing all that

Comment: same patteren of initing a empty list and appending the values inside your loop: `idxs = []`, put  `idxs.append(index)` inside your loop

Comment: `seq = [*range(7, 30, 4)]` is invalid in Python 3.4 and lower.

Comment: @wjandrea OP didn't specify a version, but is using Python 3 per the print statement. If you're using 3, there's no reason you should still be on 3.4.

Comment: I'm running Python 3.6, could be a version difference, looks like 2.7 can just use `seq = range(7, 30, 4)`

Comment: @jhpratt Yes, you're right. And anyway I forgot you can do `list(range(7, 30, 4))`...